# How to reference figures by the order their reference appears in the text rather than the order the figure appears in the text

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions

I have a two page document with three figures, A and B is small and C is big. Therefore in this document I have my text all on one page and then on the second page my three figures. To make best use of the space I have placed A and B at the top of the page (side by side) and C underneath them. However, this means that latex has labeled A as figure.1, B as figure.2 and C as figure.3 as this is the order they appear, but since my text talks about the figures in a difference order (A, C, B) this means that in my text the figure references are out of order as (Fig.1, Fig.3 and Fig.2).

Is there anyway to get latex to label the figures by the order I reference them in the text rather than the way they physically appear in the document?

I am including the figures in my text using:

```
\begin{Figure}
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, left]{Graphic}
 \captionof{figure}{\scriptsize Figure A   }
 \label{Figure A}
\end{Figure}
```

Comment: How are you inserting the Fig.1 etc. text? A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be helpful :-) Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: But doing so your figure captions will look out of order, i.e: first caption is Fig.1, then Fig.3 and finally Fig.2 This is unusual, In addition, which would be the correct ordering for listing them in the "List of figures"?

Comment: Hi darthbith, Sorry I wasnt really sure how to do a minimal working example with latex as I have only just started with it. Ill edit my post to show how im inserting the figures. Hi JlDiaz, Im aware one or the other will be out of order but its better for it to be in order in the text rather than the actual figures themselves

Comment: Alternately, depending on the content, you could label the figures 1a, 1b, and 1c.  That way, referring to 1c prior to 1b won't seem so awkward.

Comment: You can send a comment to a particular user by entering `@` before their username like @Paul

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Is there no way of doing it without the 1a, 1b, 1c method? The figures arent related so it would be a bit strange to label them in that order

Comment: If they are not related, then it wouldn't make sense.  I was reading into your question that they might be related.  But I was mistaken.

Comment: You can manually override the figure counter is a way to do it, though I subscribe to JLDiaz' concern that it would look weird.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes so theres no option to get the figure numbers derived from when theyre first mentioned in the text, it would have to be done manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done manually, by jiggling the figure counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
First cite figure~\ref{Figure A}, 
then figure~\ref{Figure B}, and finally
figure~\ref{Figure C},
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Graphic}
 \caption{\scriptsize Figure A   }
 \label{Figure A}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Graphic}
 \caption{\scriptsize Figure C   }
 \label{Figure C}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-2}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,height=.4\textwidth]{Graphic}
 \caption{\scriptsize Figure B   }
 \label{Figure B}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\clearpage
\thefigure
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]